# PHP SOAP Clients http headers Error

Tags: php, web-services, wcf, soap

I need to consume a web service https://www.example.com/example.svc?wsdl in PHP. For this purpose, I am using PHP SOAP client. The code snippet like below:

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://www.example.com/example.svc?wsdl",
    array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
        'location'=>'https://www.example.com/example.svc',
        'login'=> '#####',
        'password'=> '#######',
        'exceptions'=>true,
        'trace'=>1,
        'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        'encoding'=>'UTF-8',
        'connection_timeout' => 500,
        'keep_alive' =>false));

$client->__call('getProductList',array());
```

However, when I run this its through following error:

```
Warning: SoapClient::__doRequest(): SSL: The operation completed successfully. in E:\location\test1.php on line 37

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Error Fetching http headers in E:\location\test1:37 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'https://travius...', 'Travius/ITraviu...', 2, 0) #1 E:\location\test1(37): SoapClient->__call('getProductList', Array) #2 {main} thrown in E:\location\test1.php on line 37
```

I am struggling several days to solve the error but can't figure out. I tried the different solution in stack overflow like `'keep_alive' =>false`, `connection_timeout`  but nothing works.

I also try with php nusoap library. its request and  response are like following:

```
Error

HTTP Error: Unsupported HTTP response status 400 Bad Request (soapclient->response has contents of the response)

Request

POST /#####.svc?wsdl HTTP/1.0
Host: #####.#####.eu
User-Agent: NuSOAP/0.9.5 (1.123)
Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8; charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: ""
Authorization: Basic RGVtb2FwaTpEdXE1dmRWdA==
Content-Length: 529

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><GetProduct><parameters><intProductID xsi:type="xsd:int">1266</intProductID><lang xsi:type="xsd:string">CN</lang></parameters></GetProduct></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

Response

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 02 Oct 2017 16:03:04 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

**Please note that this web service works fine in .Net application.** 
 Any help highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please elaborate on where "MySoapClient" came from and an actual WSDL that throws this error. Based on the error, it looks like you're using nusoap, which works fine in general.

Comment: You should try to use native php soapclient and see if it helps. You can follow the guide on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29934167/set-up-php-soap-extension-in-windows and it should be quite easy to test.

Comment: You can also see that some users have found issues with nusoap connecting to C#(.Net) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15402233/which-is-better-php-soap-or-nusoap#comment54533941_15402304

Comment: Have you tried loading the WSDL into a tool like SOAPUI? I would also ask the .Net developer if the contract is compatible with clients outside of .Net. Its very easy to write a WCF service that is only consumable from .Net.

Comment: This error is often raised when there are communication/network/protocol issues. Have you tried the solutions posted here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403486/error-fetching-http-headers-in-soapclient) ?

Comment: I already tried that  solution but same results.

Comment: A 400 bad request means that the request is missing something which is expected server side, may be you are not passing all the correct parameters? Is this is a public facing WSDL one can test or your internal?

Comment: You can check this from here: https://traviusws.travius.eu/TraviusWS.svc

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php "For HTTPS client certificate authentication use local_cert and passphrase options. An authentication may be supplied in the authentication option. The authentication method may be either SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_BASIC (default) or SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_DIGEST."

Comment: Your URL is not a valid SoapServer.  It is a test/example URL only.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the error that you posted in your question please change the following line.

```
$client->__call('getProductList',array());
```

with something like this

```
$client = false;
try {
$client = new SoapClient("https://www.example.com/example.svc?wsdl",
    array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
        'location'=>'https://www.example.com/example.svc',
        'login'=> '#####',
        'password'=> '#######',
        'exceptions'=>true,
        'trace'=>1,
        'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        'encoding'=>'UTF-8',
        'connection_timeout' => 500,
        'keep_alive' =>false));
} catch (Exception $e) {
    exit("SoapClient Error \"".$e->getMessage()."\"");
}
if(!empty($client)) {
try {
        $soapResponse = $client->__soapCall('getProductList',array());
        var_dump($soapResponse);
    }  catch (SoapFault $e) { 
        exit("Error using method \"getProductList\" having errorCode \"".$e->faultcode."\"");
    }
}
```

I don't know what php version you use (you have not posted relevant information) but i think in your case [`_call`](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.call.php) is deprecated.

> Calling this method directly is deprecated. Usually, SOAP functions
>   can be called as methods of the `SoapClient` object; in situations where
>   this is not possible or additional options are needed, use
>   `SoapClient::__soapCall()`.

Comment: I am using php version 5.6. I just try with __soapCall() but same result

Comment: @karim_fci what does same result mean? The whole snippet is wrapped up inside a try-catch block so is the script exiting with the message `Error using method \"getProductList\" having errorCode \"".$e->faultcode."\"`?

Comment: @karim_fci in addition check this post http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php#116724 if php version mentioned in that example, exactly  matches the one you use.

Comment: Implementing your solution getting following error: Warning: SoapClient::__doRequest(): SSL: The operation completed successfully. in E:\location.php on line 48

Error using method "getProductList" having errorCode "HTTP"

Comment: According to your last comment reference solution getting this error: SoapClient Error "SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://example.com/example.svc?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "https://example.com/example.svc?wsdl" "

Comment: @karim_fci since you get a 400 error the problem is in the request. I hope you don't use `example.com` as your actual url :). You have to check if method `getProductList` has parameters that have to be passed during the request. Do check if the `SoapClient` parameters cause a problem by starting with something more light e.g. `$client = new SoapClient("https://www.example.com/example.svc?wsdl",array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2, 'login'=> '#####','password'=> '#######'));`  If this is a specific web service of a vendor company then ask them for further details on method requests.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Did you try to write your soap header as wssecurity [you can see samples](https://gist.github.com/johnkary/3006526)

or this [in stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987907/how-to-implement-ws-security-1-1-in-php5)