# How do I enable soap client in xammp (php version: 7.1.11)?

Tags: php, soap, soap-client, nusoap

Installation steps:

1) Download php-soap(NuSOAP for PHP) from http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoapforphp53/

2) Open “php.ini” configuration file with an editor and find the “Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.”

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; http://php.net/extension-dir
; extension_dir = "./"
; On windows:
; extension_dir = "ext"
extension_dir = "D:/xammp/php/ext"
```

3) extract the Step#1 downloaded file contents and place in the above DIR “ext”.
It extracts into its own dir “nusoap-for-php5.3-0.7.3″.
Just copy the whole dir in ” D:/xammp/php/ext”

4) In php.ini, look for uncomment the php_soap.dll extension for it to be load.

//find the line that looks like below

```
;extension=php_soap.dll
```

//un comment it as follows:

```
extension=php_soap.dll
```

Save edited php.ini file and Close it.

5) Finally , Restart server all services and reload the server configuration file.

But phpinfo not show the soap enabled, Screen short is collected from google , just image show for soap client enabled..
[image]

What is the solution??

Comment: `Soap Client: enabled` what's the problem?

Comment: your screenshot says for both client and server "enabled".

Comment: screen is collect the google... just show example for  soap client enabled

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## With **PHP/7.3.6** Server

In XAMPP Control Panel

1. Stop Apache Server
2. Click on `Config` next to Apache
3. From dropdown select `PHP (php.ini)`
4. Ctrl+F to find `;extension=soap` remove `;` from the line.
5. Ctrl+S to save the file.
6. Start Apache again.

   extension=soap

Answer (score 0):

You can try to restart your computer, and if it does not work, see if you are fulfilling all the requirements:
http://php.net/manual/en/soap.requirements.php

Answer (score 0):

[PHP SOAP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php) is available since PHP 5.0.1 . If you are in PHP4, you have to use [NuSOAP](http://nusoap.sourceforge.net/).

Native PHP codes are usually better in performance & relatively bug free, so if PHP SOAP is available, use it. More, NuSOAP has not much documentation on their official website

Answer Ref  Link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15402313/1177750